# rotate image in around its center point in canvas

Tags: android

rotate image on canvas around its center . i tried some example from net but i am failed

if i am using `bitmap.creatbitmap` with matrix i am getting error

Please suggest me which is better

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a matrix to rotate. First you set the position (I'm using the coordinates of the bitmap's centre). Then apply a rotation. Then draw using your matrix.

```
    Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    transform.setTranslate(xOfCentre, yOfCentre);
    transform.preRotate(turnDegrees, width/2, height/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transform, null);
```

If you want your turning to be animated, then see [my answer to "animating and rotating an image..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439301/animating-and-rotating-an-image-in-a-surface-view/4090989#4090989).

Comment: in this example, what will be xOfCentre and yOfCentre?

Comment: I believe they are the coordinates of the rotation point (the pivot).