# rotate image but the image color is dim and image deformation

Tags: android, android-canvas

i want to rotate i image more time,and i cannot to do it in the onDraw Method,my code is:

```
           options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;

    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

      public void setAddBmpImage(int rotate) {

    byte[] by = getBitmapByte(rotatedBitmap);
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(by, 0, by.length, options);

     Bitmap bmpSephia = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotatedBitmap.getWidth(),   rotatedBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);
     canvas.rotate(rotate);
     canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, null);
     rotatedBitmap= bmpSephia;
     imageStartX = (screenWidth / 2 - rotatedBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
        imageStartY = (screenHeight / 2 - rotatedBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        invalidate();

}
```

through the image rotate very well,but the image is  deformation,it is very ugly ,can you tell me why,and give me a good method,thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `setAntiAlias(true)`

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);
canvas.rotate(rotate);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
```

Or

```
BitmapDrawable bmdraw = new BitmapDrawable(bmpSephia);
bmdraw.setAntiAlias(true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmdraw.getBitmap());
canvas.rotate(rotate);
```

Comment: later i will try,then give the result

Comment: i try your methods,it is no useful

Answer (score 0):

i have used @user7777 methods ,and modify Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true); then rotate the center of the image rotate ,the image-deformation is changed little alos i look at [rotate image in around its center point in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143918/rotate-image-in-around-its-center-point-in-canvas)