# How to rotate a wheel (image png) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to rotate a png image on linear layout. My image is semi circle in shape and have different colors on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Using Matrix you can do it,

Something like,

```
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refresh);
// Getting width & height of the given image.
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
// Setting post rotate to 90
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
// Rotating Bitmap
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

OR Use Animation

```
RotateAnimation rAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 359, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rAnim.setDuration(1000);
imageview.startAnimation(rAnim);
```

**EDIT:** Look at this question also [How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android)

[Animating and rotating an image in a Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439301/animating-and-rotating-an-image-in-a-surface-view)

Comment: +1 for referencing: "How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?"

Answer (score 3):

might be helpful for u to rotating image.......

```
 RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(180, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 rotate.setDuration(500);
 imageview.startAnimation(rotate);
```

first two parameter for start and end of degree.

Answer (score 1):

This is hat i have done
the timer calls the pondraw mthod after every 100micro seconds
h,w are height and width of the image

```
                    new CountDownTimer(2000, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            degrees=degrees +(rm.nextFloat()*100);
            postInvalidate();
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

put this code in ondraw method

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRotate(degrees,w/2,h/2);
    bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.wfortune_wheel);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, m, pb);
```

}