# Create a rotation animation with a Drawable in SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have a Drawable (Vector) and I want to animate it rotating like a wheel. How would I go about this problem?

This is the only question I could find similar to my problem but the issue is the answer doesn't apply to VectorDrawables: [Animating and rotating an image in a Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439301/animating-and-rotating-an-image-in-a-surface-view)

I don't have any code to show because I don't even know where to start. I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert VectorDrawable to Bitmap and than use solution from link.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```